# Is there a way to always start at 0 using math.sin() Lua

Tags: math, lua, roblox

Edit:  This question is about Roblox Lua.

I'm using `math.sin(tick())` to get a variable number and would like for it to always start at `0`. Is this possible using math.sin? Is there something else I can use other than `tick()` to make this work?

Example:

```
for i = 1, 10 do
    local a = math.sin(tick())+1
    print(a)
    wait()
end
wait(1)
for i = 1, 10 do
    local a = math.sin(tick())+1
    print(a)
    wait()
end
```

My goal is to have this number start at 0 every time and then increase from there. So, it would start at 0 then increase to 2 and then decrease back to zero and continue modulating between 0 and 2 for as long as I continue calling it. Using the example above the number starts at any arbitrary number between 0 and 2.

Comment: What is `tick` exactly? It's not a standard Lua function.

Comment: @Nicol It's a ROBLOX function, it returns the number of seconds since January 1st 1970 (I think). Has some decimal places as well.

Comment: @NicolBolas Returns the local UNIX time.

Comment: Basically a more precise ```os.time```

Comment: If you save the value of `tick()` on the first iteration, you can pass `tick() - start_time` to `math.sin()`. That would start with `1.0` rather than `0.0`, but it should give you a starting point for a solution.

Comment: @KeithThompson thx. I think I can make your suggestion work also. That's really all I needed is a constant starting point. And I think that may be more efficient than the solution I came up with.

Comment: @KeithThompson - `local a = 1 - math.cos(tick()-start_time)` starts with zero  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To non-Roblox users: [`tick()`](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Function_dump/Functions_specific_to_ROBLOX#tick) returns the local UNIX time. [`wait(t)`](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Function_dump/Functions_specific_to_ROBLOX#Wait) yields the current thread for `t` seconds, the smallest possible interval being roughly 1/30th of a second.

Given that `math.sin(0)` equals `0`, what you have to do is subtract the `tick()` inside the loop with the time the loop began at. This should make the expression inside `math.sin` start at roughly 0 at the beginning of the loop.

```
local loopstart = tick()
for i = 1, 10 do
    local a = math.sin(tick() - loopstart)+1
    print(a)
    wait()
end
```

Comment: Thank you, xaxa. This is a working solution using math.sin(tick()). @KeithThompson made the same suggestion and it works. It starts at 1 instead of 0, but the most important part is that it starts at the same number every time. Perfect. I'll except this as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I took a different approach and came up with this. It does exactly what I wanted to do with math.sin(tick()). If anyone knows other ways to accomplish this I would like to know.

```
    local n = 0
    local m = 0
    local Debounce = true

    local function SmoothStep(num)
        return num * num * (3 - 2 * num)
    end

    while Debounce do
        for i = 1, 100 do 
            wait()
            m = m+.01
            n = SmoothStep(m)
            print(n)
    if not Debounce then break end
        end

        for i = 1, 100 do
            wait() 
            m = m+.01
            n = SmoothStep(m)
            print(n)
    if not Debounce then break end
        end
    end
```

Comment: It's not *exactly* the same. If you graph the printed values, you'll see a triangle wave rather than a sine wave. If that suits your purposes, that's fine.

Comment: I see. This does suit my purpose, but yeah, it's not exactly the same. I'm editing it and adding a smoothstep function to make it closer to a true sine wave.